# How to see execution logs when I use behave + allure in Jenkins?

Tags: allure, python-behave

I used behave + allure in my Jenkins job:
Run command like this one.

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results
```

When it finish I see Allure report, all working fine.
BUT during this process I do not see anything in the Console Output only this one.

[image]

How can I see proper console output there too during execution?

Comment: I usually add logging to have more debugging info. I am not sure what you need specifically to see, but for example - if you just want to monitor a progress the you can add a couple of quick logging statements into `before_scenario` and `after_scenario` hooks to output scenario name and it's status.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple example it works, so maybe it works in your case too:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results -f pretty
```